# How do we get to the classical Higgs mass equation?

Tags: higgs

If I got it right that's $$ m_H=\sqrt{2\lambda}\nu, $$ where $\nu=246GeV$ is the non-zero VEV of the Higgs field, and $\lambda$ is the coefficient of the $\phi^4$ interaction. But how can we get to that equation?

Comment: And if I have got it right (which I may not have, or you may have read it already, sorry) its here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson

Comment: By "that equation", do you mean $m_H = \sqrt {2\lambda} \nu$ or $\nu = 246 \,\text {GeV}$?

Comment: You need to ask *How do we get from $X$ to $Y$?* If we do not know your starting point, how do we know where to begin an explanation? You also need to show effort in trying to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the following Lagrangian, which is quite similar to that of the Higgs :
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi^{\dagger} + \dfrac{1}{2}\mu^2 \phi^\dagger \phi - \dfrac{1}{4}\lambda (\phi^\dagger \phi)^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi^{\dagger} - V(\phi)
\end{equation}
First, we are looking for the vacuum expectation value of the field. Clearly, this Lagrangian is symmetric under a rotation. Therefore, we can choose any direction $e^{i\theta}$ for the minimum, and we decide to take $\phi$ to be real and positive, $\phi = \phi_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Then :
\begin{equation}
V(\phi_0) = -\mu^2 \phi_0^2/2+\lambda \phi_0^4/4
\end{equation}
The minimum is then reached for $\phi_0 = v$. This gives $v = \sqrt{\mu^2/\lambda}$.

Now, we can expand the field $\phi$ around its vacuum expectation value :
$\phi = (v+a, b)$. This means we redefine $\phi$ in terms of two fields $a$ and $b$. Injecting this into the Lagrangian, and expanding, we should get terms of various orders in $a$ and $b$. The mass term of a scalar field $S$ of mass $m$ has the form $-\frac{1}{2}m^2 S^2$. If we calculate the terms in $a^2$, we find :
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} \supset \dfrac{1}{2}\mu^2a^2 - \dfrac{1}{4}\lambda \left(v^2+2va+a^2\right)^2 = \left [\dfrac{1}{2}\lambda v^2 -\dfrac{6}{4} \lambda v^2\right]a^2 = -\lambda v^2a^2 \equiv -\dfrac{1}{2}m^2 a^2
\end{equation}
And finally :
$m = \sqrt{2\lambda}v$. Note that the field $b$ is massless.

Comment: That's really good. I just don't get why you added two fields, a and b, if after the calculations only a had any influence on the mass equation.